# Matplotlib scatter points with random color and legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Noob here but I've searched all over and cannot find any hints to help me with what I'm trying to do. I've written a python program to create a world ranking for marathon swimmers, and based on the database of results, a ranking can be generated for any given day. I want to create a not-crappy-looking chart showing a given athlete's ranking progression over time with a step chart, and overlay points to represent days that they actually competed, and what the competition was.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
dates = [list of consecutive dates]
ranks = [list of the athlete's rank of each of the dates in dates list]
race_dates = [list of dates athlete raced]
race_date_ranks = [list of the athlete's rank of each of the dates in race_date_ranks list]
race_labels = [list of races where the athlete raced (as string)]

plt.step(dates, ranks, where="post")
plt.plot(race_dates, race_date_ranks, "o")
for i, label in enumerate(race_labels):
    plt.text(race_dates[i], race_date_ranks[i], label, rotation=25, fontsize="x-small")
```

[image: visualization of matplotlib plot based on code above]

Problem is...it looks terrible and is illegible (sorry, don't have enough status points or whatever on stackoverflow to embed... some day!). What I want is to kill the last two lines of code above, thereby removing the labels, and have each of the dots representing a race be a randomly colored dot with no label. Then, add a legend with the dot color and the corresponding race label. How can I do this? Help is appreciated!

Here's more about my project if you're interested:
[https://www.marathonswimworldrankings.com](https://www.marathonswimworldrankings.com/home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the intent at this time is to eliminate the overlapping of strings, change the color of each competition, and list the competition names in the legend. The data for the graphs I created was created by retrieving the data from the link in the question. Since the name of the competition was unknown, I used the name of the link in the archive. Also, as the legend may be overflowed from the graph if there are many competition names, I specified the number of columns and the location at the top of the legend. If you are concerned about the overlap with the title, please add multiple columns on the right.

In my personal opinion, while animated ranking is a good looking graph using web technology, `matplotlib` step graph is not so good looking, so it would be better to use `ploty-dash`, etc. for richer content.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

urls = ["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G2xBxmuigH0AqUg4XnkW4HPTLKt9gj6P5fO9RZnir4w/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWKeG7QeIMQTLzmvTqif__4huX2oSub-NWaoVZsthJw/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dykR2toCcFZoWV2ytQkoYZ5YCPnFBhDPCPWeXOp-fiU/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8xy9SyaLExivaWLHJvQTtIUTibJO2HqxYoS_JPq_fY/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GMsfJot0nD0bw6J2Kc7tKJ3R4blrwUqNaNxuqJgmxw/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E_Aal5ze-lLu-tYvKCoq6iK_-TWlPLfquocH0BrU4d4/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEADAPFv-LE4dQkqBb60NnxBNdhUcxVdh3V0M1_dGmQ/edit?usp=drive_web",
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FTrt7-2RUGZrXpXiFKjD6XfOu31lFRHNYJjjnt-8YXY/edit?usp=drive_web"
       ]
compe_names = ["2022_03-31_men_10km","2022_02-28_men_10km","2022_01-31_men_10km","2021_12-31_men_10km",
               "2021_11-30_men_10km","2021_10-31_men_10km","2021_09-30_men_10km","2021_08-31_men_10km"]

data = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['name', 'pagerank', 'rank', 'competition'])
for url, compe in zip(urls, compe_names):
    r = requests.get(url)
    df_list = pd.read_html(r.text, index_col=0)
    df = df_list[0]
    df = df.loc[2:, ['A','B','C']]
    df.columns = ['name', 'pagerank', 'rank']
    df['competition'] = compe
    data = data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

data['date'] = data['competition'].apply(lambda x:x.rsplit('_',2)[0])
data['date'] = data['date'].str.replace('_', '-')
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.sort_values('date', ascending=True, inplace=True)

data = data[data['name'] == 'Gregorio Paltrinieri']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))

dates = data['date'].tolist()
ranks = data['rank'].tolist()

plt.step(dates, ranks, where="post")
for row in data.itertuples():
    plt.plot(row[5], row[3], "o", label=row[4])

plt.legend(ncol=4, loc=(0,1.05))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your effort on this, I really appreciate it. I have to admit I am having a hard time following the beginning part of your solution to get the data from my site, but the part after you import pyplot helped. This encouraged me to create a dataframe with the dates that Greg competed, his world ranking after the race, and the label of the race. I then iterate through the rows of the dataframe to plot the date and rank, and label that point with the race label. Now the problem is figuring out how to place the legend, so I am going to watch a tutorial on plotly-dash now!